# Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates won't install

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, nuget, visual-studio-2017

Trying to follow [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/) where I have the proper SDK and node installed.

Running the command `dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*` gives me the error:

> Restoring packages for
>   C:\Users\xxxx.templateengine\dotnetcli\v1.0.4\scratch\restore.csproj...
>   Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source
>   'https://ournugetserver/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.NETCore.App''.
>   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
>   Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source
>   'https://ournugetserver/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates''.
>   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
>   Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source
>   'https://tcypwv01/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates''.
>   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
>   Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source
>   'https://ournugetserver/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.NETCore.App''.
>   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
>   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\NuGet.targets(97,5): error : Failed
>   to retrieve information about 'Microsoft.NETCore.App' from remote
>   source
>   'https://ournugetserver/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.NETCore.App''.
>   [C:\Users\xxxxx.templateengine\dotnetcli\v1.0.4\scratch\restore.csproj]
>   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\NuGet.targets(97,5): error :
>   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
>   [C:\Users\xxxxx.templateengine\dotnetcli\v1.0.4\scratch\restore.csproj]

Seems related to our internal nuget server. I'm using VS 2017. Looking for a way to possibly force it to ignore our nuget server or force it to use the correct one?

Comment: I was able to get the templates installed using the yeoman method described in the article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is related to Nuget package source . By selecting only
nuget.org (https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/) source  helped me to resolve this issue. make sure, you don't have any other source selected . it was happening to me because with nuget.org , Glass Builder Server (http://build.glass.lu/guestAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc)  was also selected and it was looking package in Glass Builder Server .

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio use the shortcut `Ctrl+Q` then type `package sources` click on the first search result. You can now manage your package sources within Visual Studio. If you encounter this error with the CLI check if there is a `NuGet.config` file in the project directory from which you are restoring the packages. If so then point them to another nuget source or remove the file altogether.